# PassportJS redirect loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, passport.js, restify

Below is the code I have

```
restify = require("restify")
passport = require("passport")
GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google").Strategy

jsonContentType = (req, res, next) ->
    res.setHeader("content-type", "application/json")
    next(req, res, next)

server = restify.createServer(
    name: "Sparked API"
)

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    returnURL: "http://localhost:8080/auth/google/return"
    realm: "http://localhost:8080/"
}, (id, profile, done) ->
    done()
))

server.use(jsonContentType)

server.get("/", (req, res, next) -> 
    res.send(
        message: "hello world!"
    )
)

server.get("/auth/google", passport.authenticate("google"))

server.get("/auth/google/return", passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: "/"
    failureRedirect: "/"
}))

server.listen(8080, -> console.log("restify listening on 8080"))
```

It appears I am getting a redirect loop even with a very cut down version

```
server.get("/auth/google/return", passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: "/"
    failureRedirect: "/"
}))
```

`/` is unauthenticated URL, how is this causing a redirect loop? I also tried adding in

```
server.use(passport.initialize())
server.use(passport.session())

passport.serializeUser((user, done) ->
  done(null, user)
)

passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) ->
  done(null, obj);
)
```

but to no avail

Answer (score 5):

Your redirect loop is happening because passport can't parse the OpenId response which includes a number of query params. Restify has a [bundled query parser](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#Bundled-Plugins) you can use.

```
server.use restify.queryParser()
```

Although restify is similar to express, it does not have all of the APIs passport expects. A major one is `res.redirect` which [is used](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js#L123-L125) for the `failureRedirect` and `successRedirect` options. You'll need to set the header and status manually like so:

```
server.get "/auth/google/return", passport.authenticate("google"),
    (req, res, next) ->
        res.header 'Location', '/'
        res.send 302 # redirect status
```

With those two additions, I was able to get it working locally ([gist](https://gist.github.com/maxbeatty/8107700))

Comment: There's [connect-redirection](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-redirection) which adds the `redirect` function to `res`.  I think this should work with restify.

Comment: Thank you. I'll add here an error the server returned me to help people to find this solution in google easier: `"Object HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error content-type: application/json has no method 'redirect'"`