# Session issues with Passport.js and Restify

Tags: node.js, session, authentication, passport.js, restify

I'm trying to develop a simple proof of concept that uses Passport's Google authentication strategy with Restify and Bookshelf.js.  I would like this simple app to enable me to resolve a /sessions/google route (which invokes Google authentication) and redirect to /sessions/googleReturn upon successful authentication.  For this simple proof of concept, please assume that the table that corresponds to the User model contains a record for the user that is authenticating.

Below is the code that I'm currently experimenting with.  Currently, this code results in an endless redirect loop after authenticating.  If I remove the 'passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/' })' line within the /sessions/googleReturn route, /sessions/googleReturn resolves however req.user returns an empty object.  I'm guessing that I'm not initializing the session or binding the session to passport correctly.  The console.log output inside the passport methods appears to be suppressed, which is making this difficult to debug.  If I substitute Restify/client-sessions with express/express-session, my proof of concept works. What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

```
var restify = require('restify');
var sessions = require('client-sessions');
var passport = require('passport');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google').Strategy;
var User = require('./models/user'); // Bookshelf model

var server = restify.createServer({ name: 'test-server' });

server
  .use(sessions({
    cookieName: 'user',
    secret: 'topsecret',
    duration: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000}))
  .use(passport.initialize())
  .use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log('serialize user:', user);
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  console.log('deserialize user:', id);
  new User({ id: id }).fetch({require: true}).then(function(user) {
    done(null, user);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    done(err, null);
  });
});

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy({
    returnURL: 'http://localhost:3000/sessions/googleReturn',
    realm: 'http://localhost:3000'
  },
  function(identifier, profile, done) {
    console.log('Hello from the verify callback', identifier, profile);
    new User({ email: profile.emails[0].value }).fetch({require: true}).then(function(user) {
      done(null, user);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      done(err, null);
    });
  }
));

server.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});

server.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send(200, 'Hello from root route.');
  return next();
});

server.get(
  '/sessions/google',
  passport.authenticate('google')
);

server.get(
  '/sessions/googleReturn',
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Session user data?', req.user);
    res.send(200, 'Hello from Google auth return route.');
    return next();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the response from google auth , it says 302 moved temporarily.
Also google openid is being deprecated and replaced with google-plus sign in.

Google OpenID: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

There is a npm module for google-plus sign-in if you wish to use.

npm install passport-google-plus 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-google-plus

Comment: I have the same problems with the Facebook/Twitter/Github strategies, interestingly.  Thanks for the heads-up on the Google Plus strategy module, though.

Comment: Can you try with these changes ....       `server.get(
  '/sessions/googleReturn',
  function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Session user data?', res);
    res.send(200, 'Hello from Google auth return route.');
    return next();
  }
);`

Comment: I tried your code and it works by removing the passport.authenticate in the "/sessions/googleReturn" route and the response has the openid user info in the response **res** .

Comment: So what object under res contains the user model or the Google profile object?  I see several objects under 'res' that contains referrer information, but that doesn't seem like what I would want to use.  The passport documentation suggests that you serialize the user model to the session; the session is setup to bind a 'user' object to the 'req' object.

Comment: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google/tree/master/examples/signon is complete example using passport-google on express node application. restify is building restful api's and express for web apps. what are you trying to build? I believe using social login on an express web app makes more sense than restful api.

Comment: I'm trying to modify an existing Restify API (that currently uses a local BCrypt-based authentication system) to incorporate Passport's social and local authentication strategies.  It's not typical from what is usually expected from an API, but the workflow is as follows:  User clicks on a link on the client side -> User is redirected to authentication route on the API -> User authenticates -> User is assigned an auth token within the header that allows subsequent API requests to work -> User is redirected back to client.  This is an acceptable use pattern within the Restify community.

Comment: ok i found this question similar to yours . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631996/passportjs-redirect-loop

Comment: That's it--I needed to configure the server to use Restify's query parser.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when i ran into this problem i found that i needed to be sure that restify was prepared to parse query params. my redirect loop went away.

```
server = restify.createServer({ name: 'test-server' });
server.use(restify.queryParser());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using restify, it's redirect function is slightly different. You can simple add an override, eg:

```
function patchRedir(){
    return function( req, res, next ){
        res.redirect = function( url ){
            res.header( 'Location', url )
            res.send( 302 )
        }
        return next()
    }
}
server.get('/auth/facebook/callback', patchRedir(), passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), ( req, res, next ) => {
    // Successful
    res.send( 200 )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`client-sessions` package sets a session object in `req` with a name same as session cookie name. It defaults to `session` which means that a `req.session` object is available. I discovered that such object is needed by passport.js (well, by `passport-oauth2` actually) to make it save the user into the session. So by changing the `cookieName` in `client-sessions` config you make it use a different key for session object in `req`!

GoogleStrategy uses `passport-oauth2` as it's base and you can check the source that `req.session` is indeed required:
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2/blob/master/lib/state/session.js

There are two solutions I discovered:

1. Either use `session` cookie name
2. Make a small, "universal handler" for you restify server and put if **after** you set up session but **before** you setup passport:

   ```
   server.use((req, res, next) => {
       req.session = req.your_cookie_name;
       return next();
   });
   ```